# How to fetch a date from a datepicker on NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, datepicker, nativescript

Here is my view :

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onPageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <DatePicker day="15" month="5" year="2015" verticalAlignment="center" id="date"/> 
    <Label text="Saisissez une heure : " verticalAlignment="center"/>
    <TextField verticalAlignment="center" width="300" hint="Enter text..."/>
    <Button text="Valider" tap="see"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

I wanted to know how to get the date from this datepicker i tried that :

```
var viewModule = require("ui/core/view");
var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
var page;

exports.onPageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
};

exports.see = function() {
    dialogs.alert(viewModule.getViewById( page, "date" ).year).then(function() {

    });
};
```

but it did not work.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the getViewById method on your page variable.
Your DatePicker resides inside your page variable which - according to the docs - is a derived type of the View class which contains the getViewById method.

Changing your "see" method like this should probably work (didn't test it myself):

```
exports.see = function() {
    dialogs.alert(page.getViewById("date").year).then(function() {

    });
};
```

Comment: It not worked i got nothing, when i do : "page.getViewById("date").toString()" i get de Datepicker but the property year is not fetch. If i understand the Datepicker inherit from the view class but when we call "page.getViewById("date")" we fetch a view object no ?

Comment: I have found the solution, i have to do: " page.getViewById("date").year.toString()" to get the date.

Comment: Thanks by the way it worked but to display it i have to use toString in the alert ...

Answer (score 3):

The code for Nativescript and Ang.2 is as follows. Please note the code is for 2 datepickers within a modal box.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {ModalDialogParams} from "nativescript-angular/modal-dialog";

import {DatePicker} from "ui/date-picker";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {View} from "ui/core/view";
import {Label} from "ui/label";
import {DialogOptions} from "ui/dialogs";


@Component({
    selector: 'modal-content',
    template: `

    <StackLayout>

        <StackLayout margin="24" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" orientation="vertical">
            <Label text="From"></Label>
            <DatePicker #datePickerID [year]="dtyear2" month="2" day="2" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"> </DatePicker>

        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout margin="24" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" orientation="vertical">
            <Label text="To"></Label>
            <DatePicker #datepicker [year]="dtyear" [month]="dtmonth" [day]="dtday" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></DatePicker>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" marginTop="12">
            <Button text="Save" (tap)="close('Save')"></Button>
            <Button text="Cancel" (tap)="close('Cancel')"></Button>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class DateControlComponent {
    //        <DatePicker id="datePicker"  [(ngModel)]='datePicker' verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></DatePicker>
    public dtyear = 1970;
    public dtmonth = 1;
    public dtday = 18;

    dtyear2 = 1970;

    @ViewChild("datePickerID") datePicker: ElementRef;

    //public datePicker: datePickerModule.DatePicker = new datePickerModule.DatePicker();
    //prompt: string;

    constructor(private params: ModalDialogParams) {
        //this.prompt = params.context.promptMsg;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    public close(result: string) {

        if (result == "Save") {
            let datePickerView = <DatePicker>this.datePicker.nativeElement;
            console.log("Year " + this.dtyear);
            console.log("Year from NGModel Year " + datePickerView.year);

            this.params.closeCallback(new Date(datePickerView.year, datePickerView.month, datePickerView.day));
        }
        else {
            this.params.closeCallback(null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very helpful. Could you add an example of how to use this component please?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - {N} has updated since this post and this no longer works with 1.0+

The docs have a decent example here: [Binding Example](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-with-xml#execute-business-logic)

```
   var count = 0;
  function buttonTap(args) {
   count++;
   var sender = args.object;

   /// ****IMPORTANT var ****///
   var parent = sender.parent;

   if (parent) {


      ///*** ref the parent var above ****///
      var lbl = view.getViewById(parent, "Label1");


      if (lbl) {
          lbl.text = "You tapped " + count + " times!";
    }
    }
  }
 exports.buttonTap = buttonTap;
```